# Elixir Testing: Ensure a module defines a callback

Tags: testing, callback, elixir, behavior

I'm trying write a test that verifies that a behaviour defines the callbacks it's supposed to. How should I do this?

I have a module that defines a callback, for example:

```elixir
defmodule MyModule do
    @callback my_callback(arg :: binary) :: any
end
```

I want to ensure that `my_callback/1` is defined by `MyModule`.

Since `@callback` is an attribute, I tried calling `MyModule.__info__(:attributes)`, but the callback was not present in the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it wasn't documented except in a deprecated module at the time the question was asked, this is now documented in [Typespecs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/typespecs.html#inspecting-behaviours):

> #### Inspecting behaviours
>
> The `@callback` and `@optional_callback` attributes are used to create
>   a `behaviour_info/1` function available on the defining module. This
>   function can be used to retrieve the callbacks and optional callbacks
>   defined by that module.
>
> For example, for the `MyBehaviour` module defined in "Optional
>   callbacks" above:
>
> ```
> MyBehaviour.behaviour_info(:callbacks)
> #=> [vital_fun: 0, "MACRO-non_vital_macro": 2, non_vital_fun: 0]
> MyBehaviour.behaviour_info(:optional_callbacks)
> #=> ["MACRO-non_vital_macro": 2, non_vital_fun: 0]
> ```
>
> When using `iex`, the `IEx.Helpers.b/1` helper is also available.

Answer (score 2):

[`MyModule.behaviour_info(:callbacks)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Behaviour.html).

For unknown reason it’s mentioned only in docs for deprecated `Behaviour` module.

Beware that this function is exported if and only the module does indeed define a behaviour.

```
Integer.behaviour_info(:callbacks)       
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Integer.behaviour_info/1
   is undefined or private
```

---

Fancy discovery: one might also [define the behaviour manually](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/b37220ccfa44c0bfe1e070886a0817e76de35973/lib/elixir/test/elixir/kernel/impl_test.exs#L63-L66).

Comment: Interesting. So it seems the `@callback` attribute is used to create the `behaviour_info/1` function.

Comment: Documentation is on the erlang side: http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/modules.html#behaviour-module-attribute

Comment: Ah, that’s why I was unable to find where `behaviour_info/1` is created in _Elixir_ code. Thanks!

Comment: This is now documented in [Typespecs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/typespecs.html#inspecting-behaviours), see my answer.